# Visualforce behaviour when expections are caught

Tags: apex, visualforce, exception, button, action

I made a really weird discovery and i wanna ask if this is true and how to handle those situations.
If a VIsualforce page invokes an Apex method via commandButton or acionFunction, if an exception was thrown and catched, the page won't be rerendered and oncomplete functions are not executed.

The original Button is

```
<apex:commandButton id="accept" styleClass="accept myButton" value="Accept" action=" {!approve}" reRender="output" oncomplete="someFunction()"/>
```

For the oncomplet problem, i didn't find a work around.

For the rerendering problem, i used

```
<apex:commandButton id="accept" styleClass="accept myButton" value="Accept" action=" {!approve}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="output"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```

My guess would be, if at any time an Exception is thrown, regardless of catching it, the behaviour of the AJAX Visualforce framework changes.

Is this a known Problem? How to deal with this Problem correctly? In my case, there is always the possibility of an Exception i have to catch, so not using try/catch is not an option

Answer (score 0):

You're submitting the form twice, thus causing a race condition. The two submissions are from the apex:actionSupport and the default behavior of apex:commandButton. Handling an exception takes a few milliseconds (about 30-40), so this extra delay is causing the view state to get messed up. Change your button to:

```
<apex:commandButton 
  reRender="output" 
  id="accept" 
  styleClass="accept myButton" 
  value="Accept" 
  action="{!approve}" />
```

Add the oncomplete handler to the apex:commandButton as well, if you need post-refresh logic to be called.

Here's a working simple version that does work.

```
public class q323826 {
    public Integer counter { get; set; }
    public q323826() {
        counter = 0;
    }
    public void increment() {
        try {
            Integer i = 0 / 0;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="q323826">
    <script>
    var counter = 0;
    function updateLocal() {
        counter++;
        document.getElementById('counter').innerText = counter;
    }
    </script>
    <apex:form id="form">
        {!counter}<br />
        <apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!increment}" reRender="form" oncomplete="updateLocal()" />
    </apex:form>
    <div id="counter">
        0
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: No the action support IS the fix for the rerendering Problem. The unsolved Problem is, that the function given to the oncomplete attribute of the commandButoon will never execute if an exception was thrown, even if it was catched.

Comment: @Eleos91 Either you're oversimplifying the problem, or you've overlooked something. Here's an example where I cause an exception (divide by zero), and the page works correctly.

Comment: I'm not oversimplifying it. The action triggered by the button gets executed as intended, even if an error occurred. The only difference is, the follow up function is not executed and the page is not rerenderd. I debugged it many times. There is no state influencing difference if an error was caught.

Comment: @Eleos91 Well, this is what my code does. Can you modify my version so that it exhibits the behavior you're seeing?